# sort query result based on array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, sorting, underscore.js

i have array of id from `anotherCollection`.. after i did many calculation, i got:

```
idSortByRank = ["cxwMoC3k6kpf4mr5o","HFYjC5nuT9hKhdyFC","GiM7NCLjck6Pet8Wm"]
```

i need to return object from mongodb collection of `MyCollection` sorted/indexed by idSortByRank like this one:

```
//expected result should index/sort the same as idSortByRank

[
{"_id": "cxwMoC3k6kpf4mr5o", other field},
{"_id": "HFYjC5nuT9hKhdyFC", other field},
{"_id": "GiM7NCLjck6Pet8Wm", other field}
]
```

i did this but not sort as expected:

```
MyCollection.find({_id:{$in:idSortByRank}});
```

i don't have `rank` field in `MyCollection`

thank You so much...

Comment: You can't do this is Mongodb query. This you need to do manually after you got result from DB.

Comment: Can you explain how you want them sorted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort with the index of the given array `idSortByRank`.

```js
var idSortByRank = ["cxwMoC3k6kpf4mr5o", "HFYjC5nuT9hKhdyFC", "GiM7NCLjck6Pet8Wm"],
    data = [{ "_id": "GiM7NCLjck6Pet8Wm" }, { "_id": "HFYjC5nuT9hKhdyFC" }, { "_id": "cxwMoC3k6kpf4mr5o" }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return idSortByRank.indexOf(a._id) - idSortByRank.indexOf(b._id);
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: hello @NinaScholz thank You so much,, this working...but i don't understand about this `idSortByRank.indexOf(a._id) - idSortByRank.indexOf(b._id);`.. care to elaborate a little,,?? or maybe references for my further learning..thanks again..!!

Comment: please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). the sort function returns a value smaller than 0 if the value is smaller, 0 if the values are equal and a value greater than 0 if the value is greater then the other comparing value. so the shortest is to use the difference ebtween the indices of the `idSortByRank` array.